# Optimize MYSQL Query with Order by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have seen mysql queries with order by runs slow.

Is there any specific way to optimize queries which use order by ?

Queries without order by run very fast but with order by its always runs slow.

if any one suggest any thing on this as general solutions.

Thank You

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @madgnome should have posted as an answer.

Comment: @Graphain done, I am always reluctant to write so short answer with a link.

Comment: @madgnome: Short answers have high signal to noise ratio ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could find an exhaustive [answer on Mysql Site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) on **ORDER BY Optimization**.